# Apache reverse proxy to google.com (just for testing)

Tags: apache

I am trying to create a reverse proxy (just as a test) which maps https://www.google.com to https://myserver.net/google

This is what I did in my conf:

```
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPass "/google" "https://www.google.com"
ProxyPassReverse "/google" "https://www.google.com"
```

Doing this lets me visit `myserver.net/google` but images don't load and similarly if I type in a search query, it maps the url to `myserver.net/search` which obviously doesn't work

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - it needs to be done for every sub-url as well
So

```
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPass "/google" "https://www.google.com"
ProxyPass "/search" "https://www.google.com/search"
ProxyPass "/images" "https://www.google.com/images"
```